# Obtain absolute rotation using CMDeviceMotion?

Tags: ios, swift, accelerometer, gyroscope, cmmotionmanager

I'm building a simple game with Sprite Kit, the screen doesn't rotate but I want to know the angle the user is holding the phone for a game mechanic.

The values I want to get can be easily retrieved with the accelerometer (x, y) but I have found this to be unreliable so I'm trying to archive better results with `CMDeviceMotion`. I could obtain the equivalent to `data.acceleration.y` but I can't figure out how to get the equivalent of `data.acceleration.x`.

```
if let data = motionManager.accelerometerData? {
    let y = CGFloat(data.acceleration.y)
    let x = CGFloat(data.acceleration.x)
}

// Device Motion
if let attitude = motionManager.deviceMotion?.attitude? {
    let y = CGFloat(-attitude.pitch * 2 / M_PI) // This matches closely with data.acceleration.y
    let x = ??????????
}
```

How do I calculate the equivalent to `data.acceleration.x` using `CMDeviceMotion`?

Comment: What you want is not rotation, but the gyroscope API, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/coremotion/reference/cmmotionmanager_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I'm trying now. I got to it through experimentation so I cannot tell if it's correct, probably there is a better solution.

```
            if let attitude = motionManager.deviceMotion?.attitude? {
                 // Convert pitch and roll to [-1, 1] range
                let pitch = CGFloat(-attitude.pitch * 2 / M_PI)
                let roll = CGFloat(abs(attitude.roll) > M_PI / 2 ? (2 - abs(attitude.roll) * 2 / M_PI) * (attitude.roll > 0 ? 1 : -1) : attitude.roll * 2 / M_PI)

                // Calculate x and y
                let y = pitch
                let x = roll*(1.0-abs(pitch))
            }
```

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you want the motion manager's [device motion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/coremotion/reference/CMDeviceMotion_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CMDeviceMotion), if you want the rotation values to take gyro and accelerometer input into account. According to the docs:

> An instance of CMDeviceMotion encapsulates measurements of the attitude, rotation rate, and acceleration of a device.

So, instead of monitoring gyro data directly, monitor device motion instead. The example below demonstrates how to obtain device motion on a frame by frame basis. I've just decided to print the `CMAttitude` object directly, but from this object, you can directly access the pitch, roll, and yaw of the device ([and more](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/coremotion/reference/CMAttitude_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CMAttitude)) which if I'm not mistaken, is exactly what you're looking for.

```
import SpriteKit
import CoreMotion

class GameScene: SKScene {
    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 30.0
        motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()
    }

    override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView!) {
        motionManager.stopDeviceMotionUpdates()
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        if let attitude = motionManager.deviceMotion?.attitude? {
            println(attitude)
            let y = CGFloat(-attitude.pitch * 2 / M_PI)
            let x = CGFloat(-attitude.roll * 2 / M_PI)
        }
    }
}
```

If you're using Swift 2, there are some minor changes that need to be made, which are shown below.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 30.0
        motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()
    }

    override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {
        motionManager.stopDeviceMotionUpdates()
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        if let attitude = motionManager.deviceMotion?.attitude {
            print(attitude)
            let y = CGFloat(-attitude.pitch * 2 / M_PI)
            let x = CGFloat(-attitude.roll * 2 / M_PI)
        }
    }
}
```

For more info on this, consult [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZfTc.png).

[image]

Comment: Hi @0x7fffffff I'm trying to get the absolute rotation using the CMAttitude as you suggested, I could retrieve Y with `-attitude.pitch * 2 / M_PI` but I couldn't understand how to retrieve X. I'm adding an extra bounty for that.

Comment: @lisovaccaro I updated my code. It should help if I'm understanding the problem correctly.

Comment: hi @0x7fffffff I had been reading about pitch, roll and yaw but I haven't been able to transform it to absolute rotation. I think I've come up with an algorythm to calculate x (see my answer) but I'm not sure if it's the most reliable one.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the angle by reading the gyro data provided by CoreMotion. Initialize a CM object like so:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        motionManager.startGyroUpdates()
    }
}
```

Then in the update function, you can read it:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if let data = motionManager.gyroData {
        let x = data.rotationRate.x
        let y = data.rotationRate.y
        let z = data.rotationRate.z
    }
}
```

You can now use the x, y and z values for your game mechanic. However, note that it's giving the current rotation **rate** and not the absolute rotation. You could keep track of it yourself if that's what you need. Alternatively you could use the accelerometer data:

```
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
...
if let data = motionManager.accelerometerData {
    let x = data.acceleration.x
}
```

Comment: Hi teshel I added a bounty, could you please add the code to get the absolute rotation with both the accelerometer and the gyroscope? (The equivalents to data.acceleration.x and data.acceleration.y)